# Connecting 3 LEDs to a parallel circuit of 3 fans

Tags: led, parallel, fan

I am new to circuit building.

I am building a parallel circuit with 3 fans for a laptop cooler, 2 of them are rated 12 V / 0.09 A and one of them 12 V / 0.16 A.

I ignore the PWM functionality of the fans by using only ground and 12 V wire, meaning they will spin at full speed. However I am using a variable voltage adapter (3-12 V, 0.6 A) which I can set at multiple voltages to regulate the speed of the fans. Now I want to add 3 small blue LEDs (20 mA) to this circuit without burning them through.

What is the best way to add these LEDs to this parallel circuit of 3 fans?

They can either burn at constant brightness or vary based on the input voltage.

I was thinking about connecting them in series with a proper resistor, and then connect them in parallel to the fans but I am not sure if this is efficient/feasible.

Comment: Would you like to add each LED parallel to each fan?

Comment: This does not matter as long as it is feasible and does not short the LEDs. My initial idea was to connect the three of them in series with a suitable resistor and then connect them in parallel to the three fans (which are also connected in parallel themselves).

Comment: Yes this could be possible but depending the applied voltage to that path. What are the Operating voltages of LEDs?

Comment: The LED's (still need to buy) will be standard 5mm leds with forward Voltage drop of around 3.4 V @ 20mA

Comment: So my thought would be that I have 12V across the parallel circuit of 3 fans + the train of LEDs. Then for the LED train assuming 3.5 V drop, we need (12-3*3.5)V/0.02A=75 Ohm resistor correct?

Comment: The driving equation is absolutely correct but you have to consider that LED voltage drop is mainly dependant of its color, if this value isn't available, it can usually be determined using a multimeter "diode" setting. Typically ranges vary between 1.8v and 3.3v. Also resistors do not come in every value of ohms, the answer you get from the formula may not be available in real life. You will need to select the next nearest higher value resistor based on the number calculated above. Best of luck dear.